# Kernel of matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}$ over $k[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R=k[x,y,z]$ and let $M=\langle f_1,f_2,f_3\rangle$ where
> $$
> f_1=\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\\0\end{pmatrix},\;f_2=\begin{pmatrix}z\\0\\-x\end{pmatrix},\;f_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\z\\-y\end{pmatrix}.
> $$
> Show $M=\ker A$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}$.

**What I have so far:**

Let $f\in M$. So $f=af_1+bf_2+cf_3$ for some $a,b,c\in R$. Observe
$$
\begin{align*}
    Af&=aAf_1+bAf_2+cAf_3\\
    &=a\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\\0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z\\0\\-x\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\z\\-y\end{pmatrix}\\
    &=a(yx-xy+0z)+b(zx+0y-xz)+c(0x+zy-yz)\\
    &=0.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore $f\in\ker A$. For the reverse direction, let $g\in\ker A$. How can I write $g$ as a linear $R$-combination of the $f_1,f_2,f_3$? This shouldn't be very complicated, for some reason I just can't see it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g=(p,q,r)^t\in \ker A$ so that
$$
xp+yq+zr=0. \label{eq1}\tag{$*$}
$$
Since $k[x,y,z]=k[x,y][z]$, we may uniquely decompose $p,q$ as
\begin{align*}
p &= p_1 + z p_2, \\
q &= q_1 + z q_2
\end{align*}
with $p_1,q_1\in k[x,y]$ and $p_2, q_2\in k[x,y,z]$.

Evaluating at $z=0$, the equation \eqref{eq1} becomes $xp_1+yq_1 = 0$ in $k[x,y]$, so that $p_1=ay$, $q_1=-ax$ for some $a\in k[x,y]$.

We conclude that
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\\r\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}ay+zp_2\\-ax+zq_2\\r\end{pmatrix}
= a f_1 + \begin{pmatrix}zp_2\\zq_2\\r\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Since $af_1\in \ker A$, we know that $(zp_2, zq_2, r)^t$ is still an element of the kernel, so we have
$$
xzp_2 + yzq_2 + zr = 0,
$$
which yields
$$
r = -xp_2 - yq_2.
$$
Finally,
$$
g= a f_1 + \begin{pmatrix}zp_2\\zq_2\\-xp_2-yq_2\end{pmatrix}
= a f_1 + p_2 f_2 + q_2 f_3 \in M.
$$